# Eclipse Helios 3.6.1 debug view evaluate expression is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide

I am debugging JUnit test and at some point the expression evaluation (**CTRL+Shift+I**) became unavailable.

I am starting debug session using Java perspective -> Package Explorer view r. click on the project root and choosing "Debug -> as Junit". 
In debug view when I try to CTRL+Shift+I on some variable or expression I am getting the following message:

[image]

The Variables view shows the values properly. However the CTRL+Shift+I and the Display view react with the same error. 
The log file in the workspace metadata directory does not show any related errors (all messages there are outd-dated relative to my current debug session).

I am using Eclipse Helios 3.6.1.
Restaring IDE did not help the situation.

Any idea how to fix this annoying problem?

Comment: @Frank, update what (if you mean Eclipse - I cannot: corporate policy)?

Comment: I've never seen that before, I could imagine that would be quite frustrating

Comment: ic but I would still us a fresh eclipse instead of wasting too much time for fixing

Comment: does your variable view work?

Comment: @Michael Wiles, It does (mentioned in my question above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know which one exactly helped to fix the issue in my case but I am posting below all the voodoo things I have done to fix the problem. Hopefully, somebody would find one of them useful.

1. ‘Clean’ Your Eclipse Project: Go to Project > Clean in Eclipse
2. Refresh your project folder (right click on your project > refresh)
3. Re-build your project
4. Clean your builds (If using Ant or Maven – clean your builds)
5. ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
6. ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
7. Remove and re-add your JRE:

   7.1. Right Click on your project > properties
    7.2. Click on the Libraries tab
    7.3. Click on the JRE
    7.4. Click remove, then OK
    7.5. Repeat 1-3 again, but add the JRE again

Tips stolen from [here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207)